# Getting ancestors in MongoDb using tree structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection representing the directory structure.

[image]

I'd like to write an aggregation query that will return **all child directory IDs starting from a certain point**.

For example:

- Starting from *root*: results: *child_A*, *child_B*, *child_A_1*
- Starting from *child_a*: results: *child_A_1*

I've created the following query (in Mongo 4.2) according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup), but I'm unable to run it successfully.

```
[{
    $match: {
        _id: ObjectId('5de7a00bf3663d0805644b91')
    }
}, {
    $graphLookup: {
        from: 'documents',
        startWith: '$_id',
        connectFromField: '_id',
        connectToField: 'parentId',
        as: 'hierarchy'
    }
}]
```

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Your query works as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YOh9lfw4XtM

Answer (score 1):

It is `non-trivial` solution.

**REQUIREMENTS**

1 We need to add extra field (let's call it `level`) which indicates where document is located inside hierarchy.

```
|root        0
|-child A    1
|--child A_1 2
|-child B    1
```

2 We need to `define` previously hierarchy depth (for instance: max 3)

**LIMITATION**

In order to filter from specific level, we need to modify `root` and `children` **$match** values.

Ensure always hierarchy level:

```
root     - 0
children - 1

root     - 1
children - 2
```

**SOLUTION**

```
db.documents.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      root: [
        {
          $match: {
            level: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      children: [
        {
          $match: {
            level: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $graphLookup: {
            from: "documents",
            startWith: "$_id",
            connectFromField: "_id",
            connectToField: "parentId",
            maxDepth: 0,
            as: "hierarchy"
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "root._id": 1,
      "root.name": 1,
      "root.level": 1,
      "root.hierarchy": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$children",
          as: "sub_level",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$sub_level.parentId",
              "$root._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MM7e3c34BrJ) (max depth: 3) | [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zpi2AZmEEUb) (max depth: 4)

**EXPLANATION**

1. With `$facet` we define level structure. `root` all root directory only. `children` contains all children with level 1 + children descendants.
2. We `$filter` (merge) root and children by `parentId`
3. With `$project` and `$replaceRoot` we return original structure.

**LINKS**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/